# How to convert a TextMate Grammar (XML flavor) to either YAML or JSON flavor

Tags: visual-studio-code, grammar, vscode-extensions, textmate

Textmate grammar (.tmLanguage files) are sometimes expressed in XML format.

I would like to convert to a more readable format (i.e. JSON or YAML) to integrate in a VS Code Syntax Highlighting Extension.

To clarify what I mean, here are a few examples:

- [XML format](https://github.com/Benvie/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage/blob/master/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage)
- [YAML format](https://github.com/Benvie/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage/blob/master/JavaScriptNext.YAML-tmLanguage) (equivalent to the previous one)
- [JSON format](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/shellscript/syntaxes/shell-unix-bash.tmLanguage.json)

I could write a script in Python to do that but it would save me some time if such converter already exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [TextMate Languages](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Togusa09.tmlanguage) extension has some commands built-in for this. Screenshot from the readme:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I wrote a python script anyway, not very complex data structure.

Comment: Press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and type `Convert` to see this view. It works really fast for XML.

Comment: This extension is now unmaintained, but this fork is up-to-date: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pedro-w.tmlanguage

Comment: Isn't a python library one can use to not depend on this vscode extension?